# scapy ipv6 extension header packet being dropped

Tags: python, ipv6, scapy

So i am using scapy with linux in order to send an IPv6 HTTP request to a server after i successfully commence a 3 way TCP handshake.

The http request returns successfully if there are no extension headers (i am doing it with ipv6), but if there are then i get no response back. I doubt that the server drops the packet since i am sending it to the top servers of the world (top 1000 ipv6 enabled servers) as a part of my dissertation in order to see their compatibility. This is probably a misconfiguration.

The format atm is:

I create an IPv6 packet/IPv6ExtHdrRouting().

long story short i use all 4 available extension headers and i get no responses back, whearas if i use without i get full responses back. Why are my packets getting dropped?

All the packets are sent without any parameters in them. If that is the problem can you show me a sample initialization for each extension header in order to get a response back?

**EDIT**:

my code is quite complex, after all procedures are run however i do something like this:

site[:-1] is a website i.e. www.google.com

ip is an ipv6 address WITH extension headers.

The 3 way handshake is without extension headers as you can see, and when i do the HTTP request i use the IP with extension headers.

An ip with extension header looks like this(without lower level details such as TCP etc):

```
IPv6(dst=...)/IPv6ExtHdrHopByHop()

or 
IPv6(dst=...)/IPv6ExtHdrHopByHop()/IPv6ExtHdrFragment()


                    destination=getIPv6Addr(site[:-1])
                    ip.dst=destination
                    syn = IPv6(dst=getIPv6Addr(site[:-1]))/TCP(sport=12345,dport=80, flags='S', seq=1000)#flag S is syn packet
                    syn_ack_rcv = sr1(syn,timeout=1)


                    my_ack = syn_ack_rcv.seq + 1
                    ack=IPv6(dst=getIPv6Addr(site[:-1]))/TCP(sport=12345,dport=80, flags='A', seq=1001, ack=my_ack)#flag S is syn packet
                    send(ack)    

                    httpRequest = 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:' +site[:-1] +"\r\n\r\n"
                    http=ip/TCP(sport=11235,dport=80,seq=1002, ack=my_ack)/httpRequest
                    answers = sr1(http,timeout=1)
```

Comment: Before we show any samples, how about you show your own sample code first?

Comment: @JeremyVisser The question is now updated with code.